How to Implement Transposition Tables with Alpha-Beta Pruning in a Minimax Search
I'm programming a chess engine, and recently I've been trying to implement transposition tables into my minimax algorithm. Before I added transposition tables, the minimax ran perfectly with alpha-beta pruning. Once I added transposition tables, the algorithm ran much faster but output much worse moves. I haven't been able to find any problems with my implementation of the algorithm, but something must be wrong. As best I can tell, this implementation of transposition tables should work. Thanks!
Here's a code snippet from my minimax function. If I set useTranspositions to false, the code runs perfectly, but if I set it to true, it breaks.
            best = max ? float.MinValue : float.MaxValue;

            foreach (Move move in orderedMoves)
            {
                _board.MakeMove(move.start, move.end);

                ulong zobristHash = _board.zobristHashes[^1];
                if (_transpositionTable.TryGetValue(zobristHash, out TranspositionEntry entry))
                {
                    if (entry.depth >= depth && useTranspositions)
                    {
                        switch (entry.nodeType)
                        {
                            case NodeType.Exact:
                                _board.UnMakeMove();
                                return entry.evaluation;
                            case NodeType.LowerBound:
                                if (entry.evaluation > alpha) alpha = entry.evaluation;
                                break;
                            case NodeType.UpperBound:
                                if (entry.evaluation < beta) beta = entry.evaluation;
                                break;
                        }

                        if (alpha >= beta)
                        {
                            _board.UnMakeMove();
                            return Math.Max(entry.evaluation, best);
                        }
                    }
                }

                float eval = Minimax(depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max);

                if (useTranspositions)
                {
                    if (eval <= alpha)
                        _transpositionTable[zobristHash] = new TranspositionEntry(depth, eval, NodeType.UpperBound);
                    else if (eval >= beta)
                        _transpositionTable[zobristHash] = new TranspositionEntry(depth, eval, NodeType.LowerBound);
                    else
                        _transpositionTable[zobristHash] = new TranspositionEntry(depth, eval, NodeType.Exact);
                }

                _board.UnMakeMove();

                if (max)
                {
                    if (eval > best && depth == _maxDepth)
                        _bestMove = new Move(move.start, move.end);
                    best = Math.Max(best, eval);
                    alpha = Math.Max(alpha, eval);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (eval < best && depth == _maxDepth)
                        _bestMove = new Move(move.start, move.end);
                    best = Math.Min(best, eval);
                    beta = Math.Min(beta, eval);
                }
                if (beta <= alpha)
                    break;
            }

            return best;


I've already checked the validity of the zobrist hashes, and I know that somehow my implementation of transposition tables is the problem.
